# clear the selected options after alert message is displayed jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, reactjs

- First option is the default, so the text of the options from other options is retrieved and compared.
- Now, after displaying an alert message, I want to clear the option selected in No 2 and 3 but not No. 1 which is the default.

> Link https://jsfiddle.net/fswygznq/1/

```
 function check(){
        var $fruits = [];
        $("select.fruits").each(function() {
          var $two = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
          $fruits.push($two)
        })
        for ($i= 1; $i < $fruits.length; $i++) {
            for ($j= 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
            if ($fruits[$i] == "Apple" && $fruits[$i+$j] == "Banana") {
               alert ("Since you have selected Apple, you cannot select Banana");
              $("select.fruits").val(""); // this one clears all the options including the default**
              return false;
            }
            if ($fruits[$i] == "Banana" && $fruits[$i+$j] == "Apple") {
              alert ("Since you have selected Banana, you cannot select Apple");
               $("select.fruits").val(""); // this one clears all the options including the default
              return false;
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is not select the first option element when using this selector:

```js
$("select.fruits").val("");
```

The most readable way to remove it would be to use `not`

```js
$("select.fruits").not(':first').val("");
```

But using [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) should be quicker because it does not work with the DOM, it only removes the element from the array.

```js
$("select.fruits").slice(1).val("");
```

Check the snippet below:

```js
function check() {
  var $fruits = [];
  $("select.fruits").each(function() {
    var $two = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $fruits.push($two)
  })
  for ($i = 0; $i < $fruits.length; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
      if ($fruits[$i] == "Apple" && $fruits[$i + $j] == "Banana") {
        alert("Since you have selected Apple, you cannot select Banana");
        clearFields();
        return false;
      }
      if ($fruits[$i] == "Banana" && $fruits[$i + $j] == "Apple") {
        alert("Since you have selected Banana, you cannot select Apple");
        clearFields();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

function clearFields() {
  $("select.fruits").slice(1).val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Fruits</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">1</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">2</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">3</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">4</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick=check()>
  Submit
</button>
```

#### UPDATE: Clear only *error* fields.

To clear only the fields that produced the *error* you can pass the error condition to the `clearFields()` function and use it to [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
clearFields(condition) {
  $("select.fruits").slice(1)
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).children('option:selected').text() === condition;
    }).val("");
}
```

```js
function check() {
  var $fruits = [];
  $("select.fruits").each(function() {
    var $two = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $fruits.push($two)
  })
  for ($i = 0; $i < $fruits.length; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
      if ($fruits[$i] == "Apple" && $fruits[$i + $j] == "Banana") {
        alert("Since you have selected Apple, you cannot select Banana");
        clearFields("Banana");
        return false;
      }
      if ($fruits[$i] == "Banana" && $fruits[$i + $j] == "Apple") {
        alert("Since you have selected Banana, you cannot select Apple");
        clearFields("Apple");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

function clearFields(condition) {
  $("select.fruits").slice(1)
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).children('option:selected').text() === condition;
    }).val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Fruits</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">1</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">2</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">3</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">4</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick=check()>
  Submit
</button>
```

Comment: 'm sorry, I have a question. What if I want to clear only the fields where an error has occurred. For example, Select Apple in No 2, Select Banana in No 3, and Select Orange in No 4, now selecting Apple and Banana is an error, so the only field that has selected Apple and Banana should be cleared not orange.

Comment: You can filter the resulting element set and clear only the ones that match your condition, see the update @Stephanie.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @Stephanie any reason why you unaccepted the answer? I thought it solved your problem. I am curious about why the other answer was better, that code snippet does not work for me, nothing happens when you click the button.

Comment: I'm sorry. I accept your answer. It did help me with what I was looking for. I just didn’t know that I couldn’t accept two answers from two people. Apologies for that! And again thank you for helping out.

Comment: @Stephanie thanks. If you thought that multiple answers were useful, you can vote on them, same as with other questions that you also find useful, have a look at [help someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to see how that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For do that you can profit the `index argument` of each function **callback** like that:

```
$("select.fruits").each(function(index, element){
           
    index != 0 ? $(element).val("") : null;
             
});
```

```js
function check(){
    var $fruits = [];
    $("select.fruits").each(function() {
      var $two = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
      $fruits.push($two)
    })
    for ($i= 1; $i < $fruits.length; $i++) {
        for ($j= 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
        if ($fruits[$i] == "Apple" && $fruits[$i+$j] == "Banana") {
           alert ("Since you have selected Apple, you cannot select Banana");
          $("select.fruits").each(function(index, element){
           
                index != 0 ? $(element).val("") : null;
             
           });
          return false;
        }
        if ($fruits[$i] == "Banana" && $fruits[$i+$j] == "Apple") {
          alert ("Since you have selected Banana, you cannot select Apple");
           $("select.fruits").each(function(index, element){
           
                index != 0 ? $(element).val("") : null;
             
           });
          return false;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Fruits</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">1</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">2</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="num">3</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="num">4</td>
      <td>
        <select class="fruits">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Apple</option>
          <option value="2">Banana</option>
          <option value="3">Orange</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick= check()>
  Submit
</button>
```